# Zombie exception survives being catched

Tags: java, linux, exception, browser, libgdx

I've got a really weird problem trying to use `Gdx.net.openURI(String)` from the LibGDX game engine. It's a method supposed to simply open a page in my browser. It returns true if it works and false if it doesn't. **It works** (opens the page) and returns true but a random exception shows up in my console and this exception isn't catched.

```
boolean opened;
try
{
    opened = Gdx.net.openURI(DONATE_URL); //at net.jumpai.client.menu.DonateDialog.<init>(DonateDialog.java:30)
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    opened = false;
}

// some other code that is always executed
```

And here's the output I get:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "sensible-browser": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:485)
    at org.lwjgl.LWJGLUtil$1.run(LWJGLUtil.java:406)
    at org.lwjgl.LWJGLUtil$1.run(LWJGLUtil.java:404)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.LWJGLUtil.execPrivileged(LWJGLUtil.java:404)
    at org.lwjgl.LinuxSysImplementation.openURL(LinuxSysImplementation.java:78)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.openURL(Sys.java:257)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglNet.openURI(LwjglNet.java:66)
    at net.jumpai.client.menu.DonateDialog.<init>(DonateDialog.java:30)
    at net.jumpai.client.world.online.OnlineWorldScreen.donateClicked(OnlineWorldScreen.java:434)
    at net.jumpai.util.event.ListenableImpl.trigger(ListenableImpl.java:25)
    at net.jumpai.client.menu.AccountMenu.lambda$new$0(AccountMenu.java:54)
    at net.jumpai.util.ui.listener.ClickAdapter.lambda$new$0(ClickAdapter.java:43)
    at net.jumpai.util.ui.listener.ClickAdapter.clicked(ClickAdapter.java:50)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.ClickListener.touchUp(ClickListener.java:89)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.InputListener.handle(InputListener.java:59)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage.touchUp(Stage.java:351)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.InputMultiplexer.touchUp(InputMultiplexer.java:96)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglInput.processEvents(LwjglInput.java:332)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:217)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:126)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 22 more
```

I made sure this code isn't executing twice, this problem isn't a case of one time working and the other not working. I'm truly impressed by this. Is this a real exeption? I don't get where it could be catched and printed. How to prevent it from happening?

I'm on ArchLinux and my browser is Chromium.

Comment: While I'm not particularly familiar with libGDX, might openURI have a try-catch inside it which outputs the exception? Your outer try-catch won't catch it if it's already caught.

What does 'opened' output after that code? I'm guessing it's false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Perry Monschau mentionned in the command, the exception was printed by a `try`-`catch` of a inner method called by `Gdx.net.openURI()`.

So I made a method to avoid unwanted errors in the console:

```
public static boolean openURI(String uri)
{
    PrintStream prevErr = System.err;
    try
    {
        System.setErr(NullPrintStream.instance);
    }
    catch(SecurityException ignored)
    {
        return Gdx.net.openURI(uri);
    }

    try
    {

        return Gdx.net.openURI(uri);
    }
    finally
    {
        System.setErr(prevErr);
    }
}
```

The method that is printing the stuff in the console without asking first is LinuxSysImplementation from LWJGL (comments not mine):

```
// Linux may as well resort to pure Java hackery, as there's no Linux native way of doing it
// right anyway.

String[] browsers = {"sensible-browser", "xdg-open", "google-chrome", "chromium", "firefox", "iceweasel", "mozilla", "opera", "konqueror", "nautilus", "galeon", "netscape"};

for ( final String browser : browsers ) {
    try {
        LWJGLUtil.execPrivileged(new String[] { browser, url });
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Ignore
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These exceptions are being thrown in parallel threads, so they couldn't be catched in your main thread. Printing to console is default behaviour of handling exceptions in Java. Try to use `Thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler()` method, which could help you define more specific behaviour for dealing with the situation.